# Use two forms having MDI container active

Tags: c#

I have a main form with a MDI container active as well as a childform with a MDI container active. I want child form with mdi container act as parent to another form while main form is a mdi parent to child form with mdi container. How can  I achieve this. I tried with below code for both the case but it showed error stating " A form cannot be Mdi parent as well as Mdi Child"

```
enter code here myform.MdiParent = this;
        myform.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot - the message is quite clear about that. It's simply a limitation of the system. MDI is very old, and hasn't been updated in quite a long time.

If you need some alternatives, you could look at making windows not top-level, for example. The windows behave a bit differently (both from MDI and normal windows), but depending on your actual needs, they might be sufficient (or even better than MDI in the first place).